# Looking for the Agda module that contains decidable equality for lists

Tags: equality, agda, decidable

Given two lists xs and ys, I would like to obtain a value of Dec(xs ≡ ys).
Does any one know the name of the standard library module which contains such an operator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in [`Data.List.Properties`](http://agda.github.io/agda-stdlib/Data.List.Properties.html#2520) under the name `≡-dec`